# Why no output using Word2Vec?

Tags: python, nltk, word2vec

I have a dataframe `DF` that looks like

```
index posts
0     <div class="content">A number of  <br/><br/>three  ... </div>
1     <div class="content">Stack ... <br/><br/>overflow  ... </div>
...
```

I then try to tokenize each `posts` with:

```
sentences=[]
for post in DF["posts"]:
     sentences += utility.tosentences(post, tokenizer)
```

I then run Word2Vec using the below:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s',\
level=logging.INFO)

num_features = 100
min_word_count = 7
num_workers = 2
context = 5
downsampling = 1e-5

print "Training model..."
model = word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences,     workers=num_workers, \
        size=num_features, min_count = min_word_count, \
        window = context, sample = downsampling)

model.init_sims(replace=True)

Word2Vec.load()
model_name = "what"
model.save(model_name)
print "finished"
```

I then tested the below

```
model.doesnt_match("travel no Warning health".split())
```

However, it didn't produce an output at all

I don't understand the meaning of the large output I got above. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0):

The function `model.doesnt_match()` doesn't print anything out; it returns a value. **Print** the returned value to see the output.

If you were copy-pasting from this [`word2vec` tutorial](http://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/): It's showing you the output you'd see if you ran these commands in the interactive console. (Also, it assumes that you understand what you're doing.)